# How to place Spring MVC's JSON response into the table in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring, jsp

This is how my AJAX script looks like:

```
<script>
function addToCart(itemId) {
    var url = "./addToCart/" + itemId;
    $.get(url, function(response){
        $('#shoppingCartId').text(response);
    });
}
</script>
```

It gets an itemId from the JSP, calls the controller method below with this itemId. This is the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addToCart/{itemId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ShoppingCart addToCart(@PathVariable Long itemId, @ModelAttribute ShoppingCart shoppingCart) {

    Item item = itemService.getItemWithId(itemId);
    if(item != null) {
        shoppingCartService.addItem(shoppingCart, item);
    }

    return shoppingCart;
}
```

The question is, I would like to place the response (Shopping Cart Object) into this table, which is on the same jsp. But How?:

```
<div class="span2" id="shoppingCartId">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <td><b>#</b></td>
            <td><b>NAME</b></td>
            <td><b>PRICE</b></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${shoppingCart.items}" var="item" varStatus="count">
            <tr>
                <td>${count}</td>
                <td>${item.name}</td>
                <td>${item.price}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><b>Total Price: {shoppingCart.totalPrice}</b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

If i could add the response into the request attributes, the table will be fulfilled. But how can i place this object into the request? or into the table actually?

I think the problem is here, in the success function:

```
function(response){
            $('#shoppingCartId').text(response);
        }
```

Here i get the shoppingCartId DOM object (which is the division where the table is), and set the response object (which is the shoppingCart) as Text. I can even set the attributes of shoppingCart object like this:

```
function(response){
            $('#shoppingCartId').text(response.totalPrice);
        }
```

And totalPrice of the object will be displayed on the jsp where the table is seen. But how to place this response object directly to the table? As i have already said, if i could add the response into the request attributes like any other java object, the table will be fulfilled. But how can i place this JSON object into the request? or into the table actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to render the `ShoppingCart` using jsp, then you need to remove your `@ResponseBody` annotation and instead return a value that indicates the view you would like to use to do the rendering, such as a `String` with the view name.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addToCart/{itemId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String addToCart(@PathVariable Long itemId, @ModelAttribute ShoppingCart shoppingCart) {

    Item item = itemService.getItemWithId(itemId);
    if(item != null) {
        shoppingCartService.addItem(shoppingCart, item);
    }

    return "yourViewName";
}
```

In this example, "yourViewName" represents the jsp where you are rendering your table.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS**

If you have some other need for the JavaScript object as the `response` in your `success()` method, then you will need to redraw the table from scratch on the client-side. However, if you do this, you are duplicating your view-rendering efforts: on the first visit, the view is rendered using jsp, but on subsequent ajax calls, it is redrawn using jquery, and any changes to your view would have to be modified in both places. Still, if you want to go this route, you will have to step through each of the necessary properties in your `response` object and create the corresponding HTML tags required to rebuild that table. As you noticed, simply trying `$('#shoppingCartId').text(response);` just replaces your table with some nonsense; this is because `response` has no concept of HTML built-in...it's just data.

To avoid the view-rendering duplication, I would recommend you try a different approach. The `<table>...</table>` section should be moved to its own jsp, and your ajax call should treat the response as text instead of json. When you do this, your `response` object will be the rendered table html, and THEN you can simply do `$('#shoppingCartId').html(response);` to swap out the old table for the new. For the first visit, simply include your table's jsp within the  `<div class="span2" id="shoppingCartId">...</div>` in order to reuse it. In the end your view will always be rendered using the same method, so your code will be much cleaner.

Comment: No I want to stay on the same jsp. I just want to update a part of it, where the table is seen. Thats why i just want to return a JSON object to the same view.

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I ofcourse do not want to redraw the table. So i tried your second suggestion. If i understand you right, i now have this setting: I did not change my controller method. I did not change my script. (you can see those above). I moved the table to a separate jsp. my home-jsp (which also holds the ajax call) looks like this <div class="span2" id="shoppingCartId">
   <jsp:include page="shoppingCart.jsp"/>
  </div>. It does not work yet. Did you mean something else?

Comment: But it still does not sound right.. my shoppingCart.jsp needs a request parameter named "shoppingCart" type of ShoppingCart. But i use the ajax response like this: $('#shoppingCartId').text(response).. So how will this response be transformed into a ShoppingCart object? I miss sth..

Comment: No, you will need to change your controller to something like mine. Using yours, you are still returning an object that gets transformed into JSON, but instead you need to return "myTable" so that the result is pure html that can be simply put in place. Why do you need the response "transformed into a ShoppingCart object" when all you really want to do is render an html view of that ShoppingCart?

Comment: But if i return a view name from my controller (like you have), we will be calling another view (jsp). I want to stay on the same jsp, just update a part of it, like an ajax call.

Comment: No, if you are making an ajax call, it will return the html for you to use as you wish inside the CURRENT page.

Comment: You mean, it is not possible to make an ajax call, and fullfill the table inside the same page ?? Because what you suggest is calling a jsp..

Comment: It most certainly is possible to make an ajax call and use the html (as rendered by a jsp) response to replace a portion of the current page. That's the answer I have given you, in fact. You seem to be operating under the false assumption that all ajax calls have to return JSON.

Comment: All ajax calls do not return JSON, yes. The other option is returning a String, as in your example. But in case of Spring MVC, this returned String is the name of JSP, and this jsp will be called. I do not want to call a jsp.

Comment: Incorrect. The returned string is the html produced by the jsp referenced by the view name "myTable."

Comment: Ok. Can you please explain your suggestion once again. What should i do exactly for your suggestion? I have changed my controller method. It returns the name of main.jsp where the script and table's division are located. I didn't change my script (which is written in the question description). The table is moved to another jsp which is named shoppingCart.jsp.

Comment: Ok i have made some changes based on your comments, this is my current situation; i changed the return type of my controller method. It now returns **the name of the view where the table is located**. The script is same as in the question description. Now when i click addToCart button, the script runs, it calls the controller method, and the controller method returns the view name. On the JSP, the changes will be immediately displayed BUT **as html text** like "<table class=..". I have to refresh the page in order to see the changes rendered..

Comment: I changed my success funtion from this $('#shoppingCartId').text(response); to this $('#shoppingCartId').html(response); Now it updates the table automatically. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I did not mark your answer as accepted answer yet in order to get more answers. Maybe there is another way of achieving this by returning the shopping cart as JSON object, and updating the shoppingCart session attribute with this object, while rendering the jsp. If not i will accept your answer.